# Remembering DIV state across pages. Use cookie or hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a user menu that can be shown or hidden and need to remember its state across page loads and refreshes. Now it seems to me that there are two main approaches.

1. I can store the states is the URL hash and then parse through it
   when the page loads to set the div states.
2. I can store the DIV state in a cookie and read it from here on page
   load. This seems like the easier solution.

As I am new to client side stuff, I was wondering if someone could advise me to

1. The pros and cons of either.
2. Are there security issues with the
   hash?

Comment: have you considered `localStorage`? Is it a valid solution here?

Comment: Nope, just looked at it. Would it be the preferred method?

Comment: It is the easiest to use and the most modern, so... yes.

Comment: Are there any browser compatability concerns?

Comment: unless you need to support IE7... no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach would be to store the value in cookies as it will help you to avoid the potential cross-browser issues with [local storage support in different browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage)

There are no security issues with the hash. It's just not a good practice as URLs suppose to be used for [identification and interaction](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6u8gdkOKFvoJ:tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au#section-1.2.2) with the resources by itself but not keeping the application state.
[More about URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier)

UPD: Now with the browsers adopting latest HTML5 features such as [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) you can make an advantage of it by using some handy library like [store2.js](https://github.com/nbubna/store) or any other. You can start exploring from [here](http://microjs.com/#localstorage)

Comment: although be careful with the cookies if your application is running in iframe, some browsers might block it for 'security' reasons..

Comment: so what are query strings for?

Comment: @Dementic for parameters?

Comment: Like to retain form values?

Comment: @Jursels you can store key=>value pairs in cookies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie

Comment: cookies are not always enabled. and as `FormsAuthentication` in cookieless mode works, you can store it in the Query string.

Comment: @Dementic not sure what is the question to do with Forms Authentication and .NET? My point is that URLs and parameters/hashes are not the right place to store the information.

Comment: My point is, if its good enough for microsoft, its good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

If needs to access the state with all requests, cookies are a good option(considering you only needs small amount of data and browser compatibility).Because cookie will be sent with every request.

local storage is not sent with every request and sent only when requested.if you ignore old browsers local storage is the best solution.
more about local storage : http://diveintohtml5.info/